# Сортировка вставками:)

Tags: c#, массивы, сортировка

Подскажите пожалуйста, правильно ли я реализовал сортировку вставками или у меня вышло нечто иное?

```
static int[] InsertSorting(int[] matrix)
            {
                int temp;
                for (int i = 1; i < matrix.Length; i++)
                {
                    for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)
                    {
                        if (matrix[i] < matrix[j])
                        {
                            temp = matrix[j];
                            matrix[j] = matrix[i];
                            matrix[i] = temp;
                        }
                    }
                }
                return matrix;
            }
```

Comment: Сортировка вставками — это не :), это :(.

Comment: это вроде сортировка пузырьком? @VladD?

Comment: @Grundy похоже на то

Comment: Спасибо видно я не правильно понял суть алгоритма

Comment: @Grundy: Не, пузырьком — это обмен соседних элементов, а тут поиск в уже отсортированном куске массива и вставка со сдвигом хвоста. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insertion_sort, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort

Comment: Так значит этот метод не относиться ни к "сортировке вставками" ни к "пузырьку"?

Comment: @ВасилийТерентьев, а он вообще сортирует? :-)

Comment: Страшно спорить с Владом, но, кажется, это – сортировка вставками (Insertionsort, O(N²)). По крайней мере, как алгоритм описывает Род Стивенс

Comment: @АртёмОконечников, VladD вроде и не говорил, что это не сортировка вставками :)

Comment: @Grundy Разобрался. Тогда чего вы автора пугаете? :)

Comment: @АртёмОконечников, потому что показалось что пузырек!

Comment: @АртёмОконечников надеюсь ты прав, потому что я написал метод сортировки вставками лишь прочитав его словесное описание. Просто если смотреть на примеры листинга из интернета, то это больше походит на пузырёк.

Comment: Пузырек, это когда меняешь элементы в паре местами и самый больший (меньший) всплывает на последнюю позицию. Затем итерации обмена повторяются исключая уже отсортированые элементы N - 1, N - 2, N - n. Вообще, медленные алгоритмы O(N²) внешне похожи – вставками (Insertion sort), выбором (Selection sort), пузырьком.